# Angle between two straight lines for maximizing the area bound by rectangular hyperbolas

Tags: optimization, area

How do we solve this problem in which we're given a curve $xy=1$ and two straight lines passing through the origin. The area formed by the curve and two straight lines is $\, \tfrac{1}{2} \log3\, $ when the included acute angle between the lines is $\theta$. Is there a maximum $\theta$ for which this holds true? If yes, how do we find it?

Comment: To @Jasper: Do you have some progress on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given area is easier to express if we switch to polar coordinates. Hence, we have:
$$
xy=1 \iff \rho\cos\varphi\rho\sin\varphi=1 \iff \rho^2=\frac{1}{\sin\varphi\cos\varphi}=\frac{2}{\sin2\varphi}.
$$
Now, the area of the region $D$ bounded by the graph $\rho=g(\varphi)$ between radial lines $\varphi = \alpha$ and $\varphi = \beta$ is:
$$
A(D)=\frac{1}{2}\int_\alpha^\beta g(\varphi)^2\mathrm d\varphi = \frac{1}{2}\int_\alpha^\beta \frac{2}{\sin2\varphi}\mathrm d\varphi = \ldots = \left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\tan\frac{2\varphi}{2}\right)_\alpha^\beta=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{\tan\beta}{\tan\alpha}}.
$$
Since we know that $A(D)=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln 3\,$ and $\,\theta=\beta-\alpha,\,$ all what we have to do is to maximize $\beta - \alpha\,$ on $\dfrac{\tan(\beta)}{\tan(\alpha)}=3$.

Local maximum is $\,(\beta,\alpha)=\left(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$. Hence, a maximum $\theta$ for which this holds true is $\,\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}$.

**Figure**:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome @Jasper!